# How to combine multiple columns which may or may not contain the same information in spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Okay, so I don't exactly know how to word this so I will show what I want to do.

```
| A     |   | B     |   | C     |   |
| Bob   | 1 | John  | 4 | Bob   | 7 |
| John  | 3 | Sally | 2 | John  | 3 |
| Sally | 7 |       |   | Sally | 3 |
| Chris | 3 |       |   | Hana  | 9 |
|       |   |       |   | Ruth  | 6 |
```

And I want to combine them all by the names, making it like this...

```
|       | A | B | C |
| Bob   | 1 | 4 | 7 |
| John  | 3 |   | 3 |
| Sally | 7 | 2 | 3 |
| Hana  |   |   | 9 |
| Ruth  |   |   | 6 |
| Chris | 3 |   |   |
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

I have access to OpenOffice Calc, Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to cut and paste, I assume this is either:

a) a large volume of data, or
b) something you'll have to do often,

or both.  Knowing which will help me.

In most cases, you would first create a single name list, by copying to another location each column below the other, then using Remove Duplicates.

2) Create two tables that look like this:
[image: pic of tables]

with these formulas copied down:

```
I2:  =VLOOKUP(H2,$A$2:$B$7,2,FALSE)
J2:  =VLOOKUP(H2,$C$2:$D$7,2,FALSE)
K2:  =VLOOKUP(H2,$E$2:$F$7,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Both of the above.

Comment: I added a method that should cover most cases.

Comment: @EileenR No, not sure why you were downvoted when that's definitely the simplest, most understandable process possible (and what sprung to my mind if you're going to approach this without VBA). It's even a well-written, clear answer with a helpful image attached. I'd assume the downvote came back before your edit, though, as the original was more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  It was my very first attempt at answering an Excel question on the Internet anywhere, so I was bummed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Pivot-Table, after vectorizing your table. **The advantage in this approach is that the final result is automatically update in any change** (after you press "refresh" on the Pivot-Table). Here is how you do it:

1. and another column after each value column, with the `A`,`B` and `C` repeating all the way to the end of the table. This could be done very quickly, and I guess it won't be a problem.
2. Define all the range of the table as a named range (`data` hereafter), and use the following formula to vectorize it all:

   `=OFFSET(data,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($K$2))/COLUMNS(data)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($K$2),COLUMNS(data)),1,1)`

   while `$K$2` is the first cell of the vector (where you paste the formula), and you just drug it all the way down until you reach the end of the data:

   [image: combining columns]

   in this example column `K` has all the values from the table.
3. With three simple formulas break down the vector to three columns (and give the column som meaningful names):

   in column `L` above: `=IF(AND(ISTEXT($K2),LEN($K2)>1),$K2,"")`
   in column `M` above: `=IF(AND(ISTEXT($K2),LEN($K2)>1),$K4,"")`
   in column `N` above: `=IF(AND(ISTEXT($K2),LEN($K2)>1),$K3,"")`

   I assume here that you can distinguish by a rule between what is a `Name` and what is equivalent to `A,B,C`. If the logical rules above not fit your specific situation, change to match your data.
4. Create a Pivot-Table based upon this columns to cross tabulate them as you want:

   [image: Pivot]

If you need more explanation on any of the steps, feel free to comment me ;)